# Chromium doesn't render <pre> tag correctly?

Tags: google-chrome

Firefox 3 and 4 renders [this page](http://computing.tshepang.net/what-i-do-after-debian-installation) nicely (I get a horizontally-scrollable view, instead of an overlap), but both Epiphany and Chromium don't. What's up with the inconsistency? Is this a bug in WebKit?

Comment: I doubt if the question makes sense here.

Comment: @phy Where d u think it's most suitable?

Comment: @Tshepang: at the Chromium bug tracker, apparently.

Comment: @alex I don't even know if it's a bug. Maybe it's a bug on Firefox side, as in, maybe shouln't render the page like that.

Comment: That page nearly identical between Chromium and Firefox on my machine.  What version of Chromium are you trying?

Comment: Chromium is 9.0.x. Do you get the horizontal scrolling on the <pre> tag with your Chromium version?

Answer (score 1):

The scroll isn't showing up in IE 8 either.

Considering the area doesn't have an overflow setting my guess is that Firefox is defaulting to `overflow:scroll` while the others have defaulted to `overflow:none`.

You might try explicitly setting that in your style sheet.